# Как добавить средства сборки v80(Visual Studio 2005 C++) в Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно добавить эту платформу. Никак не могу, необходимо скомпилировать проект. Он при загрузке выдает следующее: warning  : Невозможно найти средства сборки для v80. Установите v80, чтобы выполнить сборку с использованием средств сборки v80.
Как извлечь эти средства из 2005 студии и добавить в 2019?

Пожалуйста, не предлагайте переписать его под новую платформу, необходимо скомпилировать именно с 2005.
Сам проект написан в 2019 студии и при попытке загрузить в 2005 студию выдает ошибку о том, что он был написан в новой версии и его не загрузить.

Comment: Слышали что-нибудь об обратной совместимости?

Comment: Вероятно, это должно помочь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32839098/3240681

Comment: Проще будет создать новый проект для 2005 студии.

Comment: Проще было сказать, что необходимо установить все Visual Studio 2005-2019 и добавить тулсеты в MSBuild по пути C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v80. Но вы начали издалека. Спасибо и на этом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот оно решение, мало ли кто еще столкнется с подобным. Необходимо установить все Visual Studio 2005-2019 и добавить тулсеты в MSBuild по пути C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v80. Тулсеты можно взять здесь https://github.com/georgeto/Daffodil/tree/master/Platforms/X64/v80